# Custom controller containment and navigation bar height

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm implementing a custom containment view controller. The child VC's are navigation controllers and are full screen. To perform the transition/animation I'm using:

```
// controller hierarchy setup
parentVC.addChildViewController(targetVC)
currentVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
// position target
targetVC.view.frame = currentVC.view.frame
targetVC.view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth
// swap em
parentVC.transitionFromViewController(currentVC, toViewController: targetVC, duration: 0.3, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {}) { (finished) -> Void in
    // controller hierarchy complete
    self.currentVC.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.targetVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self.parentVC)
}
```

It works fine with the big exception that the navigation bar underlaps the status bar until the animation is complete, at which point it pops into place with the extra 20px in height.

Since the frame is being set before the animation, and the animation does not affect the frame, I'm at a loss... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the desired effect by ditching `transitionFromViewCon...` and just using UIView's `animateWithDuration`. Seems like figuring out how to stick with `transitionFromViewCon...` would be ideal, but I'll roll with this for now.

```
    // controller hierarchy setup
    parentVC.addChildViewController(targetVC)
    currentVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    // position target
    targetVC.view.alpha = 0
    parentVC.view.addSubview(targetVC.view)
    // swap em
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        // crossfade
        self.targetVC.view.alpha = 1
        self.currentVC.view.alpha = 0
    }, { (finished) -> Void in
        self.currentVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        // controller hierarchy complete
        self.currentVC.removeFromParentViewController()
        self.targetVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self.parentVC)
    })
```